# How do I dynamically assign the number of cores per node?

Tags: slurm

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=Parallel# Job name
#SBATCH --output=slurmdiv.out# Output file name
#SBATCH --error=slurmdiv.err # Error file name
#SBATCH --partition=hadoop# Queue
#SBATCH --nodes = 1
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00# Time limit
```

The above script does not work without specifying --ntasks-per-node directive. The number of cores per node depends on the queue being used. I would like to assign the maximum number of cores per node without having to specify it ahead of time in the slurm script. I'm using this to run an R script that uses detectCores() and mclapply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `#SBATCH --exclusive`  parameter to your submission script so that Slurm will allocate a full node for your job, without the need to specify explicitly a specific number of tasks. Then you can use `detectCores()` in your script.

Comment: I tried it but it is still asking me to specify the number of cores and when I do, it just allocated the cores specified. Is there something I'm doing wrong?